# Install FFMPEG on XAMPP

Tags: php, windows-xp, ffmpeg, xampp

I have installed xampp 1.7.4 with php version 5.3.5 on windows xp. 
How to install ffmpeg in xampp with php 5.3.5 on windows xp?

Comment: Have you tried simply downloading and extracting a [ffmpeg binary](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow steps from [here](http://ukphpdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-install-ffmpeg-in-xampp.html) or do the following steps.

1. Download ffmpeg from here: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html
2. Copy php_ffmpeg.dll from the php5 folder to the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.9-2\ext
3. Copy files from common to the windows/system32 folder
4. Add extension=php_ffmpeg.dll to php.ini file ( \apache...php.ini )
5. Restarted all services (Apache, PHP...)

And enable "extension=php_ffmpeg.dll" directive in your php.ini.

Comment: I have tried it, but it does not work for me. However I am not using wampp. Istead i m using xampp. So directory structure is not same as you mentioned.

Comment: As of April 2018, this is no longer a valid answer.

Comment: How can we do this on mac PC for AMPP server?

Answer (score 6):

Sodobni-mediji.si's method worked, but some things need to be clarified.

Download: https://rapidshare.com/#!download|934l34|422916798|php_ffmpeg_v0.6.0_for_PHP_5.3.1.rar

1. unzip
2. copy ffmpeg.exe somewhere and remember the path for later use
3. move php_ffmpeg.dll to php extension dir (usually c:\xampp\php\ext)
4. move all other files to Windows\System32 (except COPYING.GPLv3.txt, readme.txt)
5. add extension=php_ffmpeg.dll to php.ini (usually c:\xampp\php\php.ini)
6. restart apache with fingers crossed
7. questions/answers http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=41913

If you are using windows 64bit, you will also need to to copy all of those dll files to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 along with C:\Windows\System32.

You will probably have problems with toGdImage(), I have no idea how to fix this...

Comment: confirmed on Windows 7 64 bit, xampp 1.7.4, php version 5.3.5, ffmpeg 0.6.0

Comment: https://rapidshare.com/#!download|934l34|422916798|php_ffmpeg_v0.6.0_for_PHP_5.3.1.rar  the link doesn't work

Comment: I guess that doesn't surprise me. I am out of sync with this topic over the past two years. I would imagine (hope) that things have changed a bit in that time... but who knows. It is so much easier to get working on linux which is where I am now...

Answer (score 4):

If above solution not working, one thing you can do is as below:

1. Go to this url: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
2. Download 32 or 64 bit (as per your system) static FFMPEG.
3. After download you can see "ffmpeg.exe' file, copy and paste this file in your xampp directory. (e.g. C:\xampp)
4. Then, set "C:\xampp" this path in your application.
5. Enjoy..

Answer (score 3):

Go to [apachefriends.org](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=32688) You will find a link to ffmpeg 0.6.0 for php 5.3.1 there.

1. Copy php_ffmpeg.dll to xampp\php\ext.
2. Copy ffmpeg.exe into root of your site or anywhere else as long you know where (you will have to define path to it in your php file)...
3. Copy everything else to windows/system32.
4. Add "extension=php_ffmpeg.dll" or remove ";" on the beginning of that line in php.ini file (xampp\php\php.ini )
5. Restart apache server... and voila :)

It worked for me on PHP 5.3.1 and 5.3.5 :)
I found this on [apachefriends.org](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=32688)

Good luck :)

Comment: This works, but some things need to be clarified. Download: https://rapidshare.com/#!download|934l34|422916798|php_ffmpeg_v0.6.0_for_PHP_5.3.1.rar

Comment: How can we do this on mac PC for AMPP server?