# How to install php_ffmpeg.dll on wamp server 2.2 windows7 64bit?

Tags: php, wamp, windows-7-x64, ffmpeg-php

I'm getting "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library: c:/wamp/.../php5.3.10/php_ffmped.dll - %1 is not Win32 application" error when run php from cli, and same error in apache error log when running as apache2 module.

I tried andswers for xampp installation
([Install FFMPEG on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977448/install-ffmpeg-on-xampp))
But they didn't work for me.

It seems that difference in xampp php module is a php compiler - MSVC6 since for wamp it is MSVC9.

I killed half a day investigation this issue. Please help me out where can I get proper libs to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible thing I can think is that maybe you don't have the correct visual c++ runtimes for your support DLLs.  If the php_ffmpeg.dll is 32 bit, then it's failing to load because it can't load its msvc* dlls or one of the other DLLs (avcodec*.dll, etc) may need appropriate runtimes installed also.  Download the latest Visual C++ 9.0 runtimes.