# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php5.4.3/ext/php_ffmpeg.dll is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: php, apache

Good day,

I am trying to install the .dll file php_ffmpeg on my windows 7 machine, and I keep getting this error:

```
[29-Jan-2013 11:37:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_ffmpeg.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0
```

Please help, I have tried to follow some online tutorials and they all come to a screaming halt in this stage..

Comment: Make sure, you've downloaded correct version (built for windows, x86 or x64 (depends on your needs) and so on).

Comment: okey, fair enough.. the question then would be, where do I find that correct version to install? because even the one I have (ffmpeg) does not specify which version it is.I was following this tutorial:

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,70245

Comment: I think you should download the version which matches the bitness of PHP, not that of Windows (e.g. if you have x86 PHP on x64 windows use the x86 version of ffmpeg DLL).

Comment: Cool, actually my pc is x64 bit, and php is also "Architecture x64" when i check the phpinfo() function, for that do you know where I can download a 64 bit php_ffmpeg.dll file?

Comment: also, isn't there a TS (thread safe) and NTS version usually? as well as v6 and v9?

Comment: I have been trying to look for something like that @mark but to no success, do you have a link i can use?

Comment: that one answer here seems to be working (confirmed by at least one other person): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977448/install-ffmpeg-on-xampp

Comment: Hi, have you solve your problem? because I'm also getting this error link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608309/copy-step-written-on-stackoverflow-to-install-ffmpeg-on-wamp-not-working