# php startup :unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php

i am getting warning  php startup:unable to load dynamic library 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll'-%1 is not a valid Win32 application
how to sole this.

Comment: Has your wamp installation been working earlier? (Either your disk is getting corrupt, or the installation files are corrupt, probably...)

Comment: Also, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582372/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-php5-4-3-ext-php-ffmpeg-dll-is-not-a?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is due to invalid dll file.

first you need to find

- Architecture -  32 bit ot 64 bit
- compiler version - VC9 or VC11
- Thread safe or Non thread safe

this can be find by open phpinfo or echoing `phpinfo()` in any php file.
then search for `Compiler`,`Architecture` and `Thread Safety`

then go to http://windows.php.net/download/ and download right Releases.
replace needed file then restart web server

Comment: phpinfo() is giving the below information
compiler MSVC11(Visual C++ 2012)
Architecture x64
thread saftey enabled                            how to know that where i did wrong

Comment: now shall i uninstall my wamp server and download VC11 x64 Thread Safe zip file .after that reinstall the wamp server?

Comment: I've wasted so much time just because I thought I was on x86... omg..thx