# Unable to load dynamic library php_ffmpeg.dll

Tags: php, windows, ffmpeg

I have downloaded the the files

- avcodec-52.dll
- avcore-0.dll
- avformat-52.dll
- avutil-50.dll
- php_ffmpeg.dll
- pthreadGC2.dll
- swscale-0.dll

Copied the php_ffmpeg.dll in php ext directory
and rest of the files in SysWOW64
and uncommented the following code
extension=php_ffmpeg.dll in php.ini
After all this wamp server gives error on starting and doesn't add ffmpeg extension

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmmD9.png)

Can someone guide that what is this error and how to resolve it , I am using windows 64 bit and php5.5.12.
This error occurs when i uncomment the php_ffmpeg.dll extension in php.ini file.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow.  I recommend not relying on a link for such a big chunk of your question, as they may break, and one of the goals here at SO is to have a resource for people in the future with the same problem as you.  Please post a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, and what the error is that you get.  Thanks

Comment: Sure Neal , I will keep this in mind for next time. Thanks for your guide.

Comment: you can edit this one.

Comment: your wamp x64 or x86??

Comment: @dass windows is x86

Comment: @Liza Ash what version of ffmpeg did you download?

Comment: i have downloded from here https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-local-server/ Please let me know if i have to download some other version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28259285/4606122 - try this one

Comment: no it is giving same error

Comment: You’re running a 32-bit version of Apache and therefore you need the 32-bit ffmpeg-php extension, not the 64-bit one.

Comment: no please answer here i am unable to use this .

Comment: http://myownhomeserver.com/2012/12/how-to-install-ffmpeg-php-php-5-4-on-windows-8-xampp-1-8-1/  ... Please refer to this link

Comment: Try this this solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977448/install-ffmpeg-on-xampp

Comment: now it is giving unable to initialize module compiled with module api error

Comment: i am using 5.5 php . plesae guide