# Can't install ffmpeg extension in xampp 3.2.2 in windows 7

Tags: php, windows, apache, ffmpeg

I'm trying to install `ffmpeg` extension but couldn't success-ed. I've `windows 7 64 bit`, `xampp version 3.2.2` with `7.1.1 PHP version` and `apache version is Apache/2.4.25 (Win32)`. Now I tried to install `ffmpeg` and get help from different forums like [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977448/install-ffmpeg-on-xampp) and other forums too but I got error instead of `ffmpeg` extension and now when I start my `xampp` software it gives me error, error title is `httpd.exe - System Error` and error is `The program can't start because php5ts.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem` image of error is also attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak8x3.png) when I click `Ok` button after few seconds again it shows the same popup error with same title and error then my `xampp's apache` starts then I start `mysql` database and it starts normally, so is there any problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone can you tell me about the problem???

Comment: Is there anyone who can tell me about the problem of installing `ffmpeg`.